# Git - Merge apenas de arquivos com conflito

Tags: git

Boa tarde!

Existe alguma maneira de fazer o merge entre duas branchs somente nos arquivos com conflitos?

Estou em uma situação onde trabalhamos com Azure e ao fazer um Pull Request ela notifica que há conflitos em dois arquivos específicos. Eu normalmente atualizo as duas branchs localmente e faço o "checkout" dos arquivos listados com conflitos.

Mas gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de fazer já o mexe com os arquivos conflitados localmente (sem precisar ficar descrevendo quais arquivos quero fazer merge)

Atenciosamente

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta mas vamos la, no git quando você da o comando

```
git checkout sua_branch

git merge master
```

pra dar merge da sua_branch com a master no caso. Se der conflito vai aparecer a seguinte mensagem

```
Auto-merging arquivo.ext
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in arquivo.ext
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

nesse caso você arruma os conflitos nos arquivos e da o seguinte comando

```
git add arquivo.ext
git commit -m "correção do conflito..."
```

deve aparecer a mensagem

```
Recorded resolution for 'arquivo.ext'.
[sua_branch 645c4e6] Merged master fixed conflict.
```

depois so seguir o fluxo